# I am getting the below error when i declare a varibale in the procedure in WAMP SERVER

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, wampserver, cursors

> "u have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
>   to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS INT
>   DEFAULT 0;"

The program is

```
  create procedure analysis1()
  BEGIN
 declare done AS INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE e_no AS INTEGER;
  declare done   AS INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE e_recieved AS   timestamp;
  DECLARE analyse  cursor for select distinct(mb.`EMAIL_NO`),ms.`EMAIL_RCVD`           from mail_body mb,mail_sub ms where mb.`Analysed`='No' and mb.`EMAIL_NO`=ms.`EMAIL_NO`;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done  = 1
  set done=0;
  open analyse ;
   imLoop: loop
  fetch analyse into e_no ,e_recieved;
  if done = 1 then leave igmLoop; end if;

   UPDATE `site_summary` SET `ACTUAL`=null,`RAG_ID`=null,`RUNNING_SINCE`=null,`DOWN_SINCE`=null 
    WHERE `SS_PID` in (select ss_pid from process where ss_id in (
    select ss_id from mail_body where email_no=e_no));
   UPDATE site_summary set `ACTUAL`='Running' 
   WHERE SS_PID in 
   (select ss_pid from process where ss_id in (
      select ss_id from mail_body where email_no=e_no ) 
     update site_summary set ACTUAL='Down' where ACTUAL=null;
    update site_summary set RAG_ID=3 where site_summary.ACTUAL='Running' and site_summary.EXPECTED='Running';
   update site_summary set RAG_ID=2 where site_summary.ACTUAL='Running' and site_summary.EXPECTED='Down'; 
     update site_summary set RAG_ID=2 where site_summary.ACTUAL='down' and site_summary.EXPECTED='Running'; 
      UPDATE `mail_body` SET `Analysed`='yes' WHERE `EMAIL_NO`=e_no;
        end loop imLoop;
      close analyse;
  END;
```

Comment: This is mysql not sql-server

Comment: See doc.: [13.6.4.1 Local Variable DECLARE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare-local-variable.html). Try for example: `DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;`.

Comment: 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ana

    BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0' at line 1       Im gettting error like this